# How to always activate the alt tag from images in the TYPO3 backend?

Tags: typo3-9.x

Our customer uses a TYPO3 9.5 LTS and complains about the fact that they always have to activate the "alt" tag in the TYPO3 backend to enter the text. We force our customer to do so to hit the W3C requirements.

So is there a way to activate the checkbox by default in the backend? Or may be to remove it at all and allow to prompt even an empty field there?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All images should have a (global) default entry for these fields(`title`, `alt-text`, `description`). Then you would see this default value and only if you want other values for this usage of the image you need to activate the field to edit.

If your editors only fill in the fields for each usage (probably always with the same data) they do additional work.

**Show them how to edit the data in the file-manager (File List modu**le):

Open the backend module `FILE`-> `Filelist`.

If you have not done yet: check `[x] Extended view` beyond the list of files and folders.

Then you will get more icons in this view which otherwise are ony available in the contextmenu.

The important icon is the pencil (edit button). it does not edit the content but the metadata of a file.

*If you insist on SEO you probably have installed the extension `filemetadata` which adds some more information fields and scheduler tasks to extract data automatically.*

So the amount of available fields to edit depends on the extensions you have installed, but the basic filds are availe by the TYPO3 core.

**If your editors upload new files they should fill in these fields to have the information available with each usage.** And only if there is a usage which needs other metadata your editors need to make this fields editable.

Comment: Is this a Typoscript setting or where can I find this global definition?

Comment: I enhanced my answer with the steps how to edit this metadata globally.

Comment: Well our customer doesn't use the fileadmin like a coder would do. They directly upload files if the create / update content elements with images.

Comment: We find the final solution. You are able to edit the file meta directly in the tt_content Element after you create the Reference with clicking on the edit icon (pencil) on the right hand side. I guess that will do. But thanks for the explanation.